# HANA SDA to SQL Server with several databases

Tags: sql-server, hana, sda

In my configuration there are several databases available in the "SQL_SERVER" remote source.

SDA only displays the database set as default for the SQL User used at ODBC level

Is it possible to display many databases through one SDA remote source ? Is it possible to have "Database2", "Database3", ... also listed under "SQL_SERVER" ?

Of course, the SQL Server user has access to all those databases.

Thanks for your help.

HANA SDA:

[image: HANA sda : screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While creating the SDI with SQL syntax, specifying
ADAPTER "odbc"
instead of
ADAPTER "mssql"

makes all database available .. :)